# hive:multiple string replace in a column

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

It's easy to replace a character one time with a function such as this:

```sql
regexp_replace(string INITIAL_STRING, string PATTERN, string REPLACEMENT)
```

**But how to deal with multiple string replacements in a column at one time?**

For example, with relation like A to @, B to #, C to Z, how would one change `"ABC"`  into `"@#Z"`?

Comment: One way is to use nested `regexp_replace(regexp_replace(...),...)` for each pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Use [translate(input, from, to)](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions) function, it translates the input string by replacing the characters present in the from string with the corresponding characters in the to string:

```
hive> select translate('initial string ABC A B C','ABC','@#Z');
OK
initial string @#Z @ # Z
Time taken: 0.063 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```